# Why was Oscar’s description of his savior that of Jesus Christ?

Tags: plot-explanation, dexter

The season 1 episode 6 of *Dexter* titled [“Return To Sender”](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Return_to_Sender_(Dexter)) starts with the boy Oscar watching Dexter from a hiding place. Dexter is worried throughout the episode that the boy’s description will match him. But then the description, as drawn by the police sketch artist, turns out to be that of Jesus Christ!

What was that all about? Did the boy try to mislead the police to try to save Dexter? Or was the sketch artist trying to save Dexter?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

When the Cuban boy is found in the trunk, *he's reciting the [Lord’s Prayer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lord's_Prayer) in Spanish*, heavily implying that he's from a religious family\background. From the [script](http://leethomson.myzen.co.uk/Dexter/Dexter_1x06_-_Return_to_Sender.pdf):

> **OSCAR** *(the faintest whisper)*: Padre nuestro que estas en los cielos. Santificado sea tu nombre. Venga tu reino. Hagase tu voluntad. En la tierra como en el cielo...

The logical conclusion, then, is that the boy simply saw Dexter as his savior and imagined he's Jesus. *It's up to us to decide whether he also did it to help Dexter who saved him from the human traffickers*, but the sketch does resemble Dexter a bit and has his eyes (which is explicitly stated in the script). However, I'm pretty sure that the sketch artist had nothing to do with it because I saw the entire show and this was never implied at any point.

Comment: I expected the same answer but you deserve the point for presentation.